# How to create a custom inspection in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

I want to create a custom inspection in PhpStorm that will flag any use of a specific PHP function as a warning. I assume I should use the Structural Search Inspection for this but if I just write the function name in the Search box, nothing happens.

Is there a way I can add this inspection without writing a full plugin?

Answer (score 0):

If Structural Search Inspection doesn't work for you, the only option is developing a plugin. See http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Developing+Custom+Language+Plugins+for+IntelliJ+IDEA#DevelopingCustomLanguagePluginsforIntelliJIDEA-CodeInspectionsandIntentions. You can also use [Open API and Plugin Development forum](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/community/idea/open_api_and_plugin_development?view=discussions&start=0).

But seems that SSR is an easier way to go... What pattern(s) did you try? See http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/ssr.html, http://blogs.jetbrains.com/yole/archives/000045.html for some hints

Comment: I wrote "func_get_args" or "func_get_args()" in the Search box. But it didn't highlight any occurence in the source code.